# IOMeter iobw.tst file

Tags: io

I am using the open source IOMeter to test the IO performance of my system. I still did not understand the use of iobw.tst file. What I mean is suppose if I start some IO process on my machine the IOMeter should show the statistics. Where does iobw.tst file fit in here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IOMeter carries the test using iobw.tst file. What I mean to say is the IOMeter actually writes and reads from that file and measures the IO performance of your system.